# JdbcTemplate is returning empty result

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

could you help me previously its giving the perfect result but now its not give me

```
private String SQL_SERVICE_CONFIGS1 = "SELECT cc.client, ac.association_code, as1.service_name, as1.service_type, as1.service_implementation, as1.endpoint_url FROM association_config ac, association_services as1,client_configs cc WHERE as1.association_id=ac.id AND cc.id=ac.client_config_id AND ac.association_code= ?";

public List<AssociationConfiguration> getAssociationConfigurations(String clientId, String associationId) {
    String sql = SQL_SERVICE_CONFIGS1;

    Object[] args = new Object[] {};
    if (associationId != null && associationId.trim().length() > 0) {

        args = new Object[] { associationId.trim() };
    }
    return (List<AssociationConfiguration>) jdbcTemplate.query(sql, args,
            new AssociationConfigurationRowMapper());
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like your query is wrong: `ac.association_code = associationId` will be the result. Is that right?

Comment: sorry  my query was correct but i incorrectly pointed to another db thanks jens